# Pipe that does nothing

Tags: bash, sh, ksh, no-op

I'm on a AIX box and need a program that when used after a pipe does nothing.

I'll be more exact. I need something like this:

```
if [ $NOSORT ] ; then
    SORTEXEC="/usr/bin/doesnothing"
else
    SORTEXEC="/usr/bin/sort -u"
fi
# BIG WHILE HERE
do

done | SORTEXEC
```

I tried to use `tee > /dev/null`, but I don't know if there is another better option available.

Can anybody help with a more appropriate program then `tee`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need `done | "$SORTEXEC"` (where the double quotes may or may not be advisable -- you cannot then have a command with arguments in the variable, but in this particular scenario you hardly want that anyway; and if you really do, putting the complex command in a function is probably a good idea for many reasons. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `tee` as follows:

```
somecommand | tee
```

This just copies stdin to stdout.

Or uUse `true` or `false`. All they do is exit `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`.

```
somecommand | true
```

Notice, every output to stdout from `somecommand` is dropped.

Another option is to use `cat`:

```
somecommand | cat
```

Comment: although the true command droped stdout, the cat and tee command worked very well.

Comment: I'd go with the `cat` solution for a generic drop-in no-op replacement for a pipeline filtering stage.

Answer (score 4):

`:` is the portable, do-nothing command in the POSIX specification.

```
if [ "$NOSORT" ] ; then
    SORTEXEC=:
else
    SORTEXEC="/usr/bin/sort -u"
fi
```

`:` is guaranteed to be a shell built-in in a POSIX-compliant shell; other commands that behave similarly may be external programs that require a new process be started to ignore the output.

However, as tripleee pointed out, strings are meant to hold data, not code. Define a shell function instead:

```
if [ "$NOSORT" ]; then
    SORTEXEC () { : ; }
else
    SORTEXEC () { /usr/bin/sort -u; }
fi

while ...; do
    ...
done | SORTEXEC
```

Comment: Better solution than mine +1^^

Comment: Define "did not work". `echo foo | :` seems to work as intended, at least in the `ksh` that ships with Mac OS X.